# How access to a security endpoint on OpenAPI with vert.x?

Tags: java, openapi, vert.x, rest-assured, vert.x-webclient

I am playing with the vert.x-openAPI module and I have my petstore.yaml with security like:

```
/pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      security:
        - ApiKeyAuth: []
```

This is the related part of the operationId on my Server side (Verticle) using a JWT Auth Handler (I will ommited the JWT Auth provider creation part from my code) :

```
 routerBuilder.setOptions(routerBuilderOptions)
      .securityHandler("ApiKeyAuth", JWTAuthHandler.create(jwtAuthProvider))
      .operation("showPetById")
      .handler(routingContext -> {
        RequestParameters params = routingContext.get(ValidationHandler.REQUEST_CONTEXT_KEY);
        Integer id = params.pathParameter("petId").getInteger();
        Optional<JsonObject> pet = getAllPets()
          .stream()
          .filter(p -> p.getInteger("id").equals(id))
          .findFirst();
        if(pet.isPresent()){
          routingContext
            .response()
            .setStatusCode(200)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json")
            .end(pet.get().encode());
        }else {
          routingContext.fail(404, new Exception("Pet not found"));
        }

      });
```

Then, I am trying from my tests access to that endpoint with a successfully (and authorization ok) response  :

```
@Test
  public void breakingTheAuth(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext vertxTestContext){

    Checkpoint checkFlag = vertxTestContext.checkpoint(2);
    //Checkpoint jwtCheck = vertxTestContext.checkpoint();
    vertxTestContext.verify(()->{
      JWTAuth jwt = loadJWTAuthprovider(vertx);
      checkFlag.flag();
      RouterBuilder.create(vertx,"petstore.yaml")
        .onSuccess(routerBuilder -> {
          routerBuilder.setOptions(FACTORY_OPTIONS)
            .securityHandler("ApiKeyAuth", JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt))
            .operation("showPetById")
            .handler(routingContext -> {
              given()
                .port(8080)
                .get("/pets/2")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);

            });
          checkFlag.flag();
        }).onFailure(throwable -> {
          vertxTestContext.failNow(throwable);
        });
    });
  }


    I would like to access to this endpoint http://localhost:8080/pets/2 with a 200 status code as a response but I always get the 401 Unauthorized (Maybe a JWTAuth problem, I've read about using oAUTH it could be a better option).
    Maybe I am missing anything, should I use the vertx-webclient to access to that endpoint?
```

Comment: why are you using `RouterBuilder` in tests? that one is supposed to be used in server side to load OpenAPI spec and mount handlers, it will not do anything for client side. Also your codes has a lot of pieces missing, the problem can be anywhere, from client that is not configured properly to server that has bad/wrong keys setup for JWT auth...

Comment: ok @mohamnag could you put some simple example of how should be the good way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: for the client side, you actually can't use any library to magically setup the security for you. OAuth is clear, you need user interactions to get your hands on a token.

Comment: for the tests, I would setup a mock OAuth server which gives you a token without interactions and change the server code so that it connects for that mock server. for example using config values.

Comment: ok, I think it has become clear to me about the generate a token to go on the security endpoints, on the other hand about mock oAuth server using config values do you have some useful links or examples? Thanks a lot mohamnag.

Comment: this one works for me very well: https://github.com/TNG/keycloak-mock

Comment: now that its more clear what you need, I assembled an answer too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `RouterBuilder` and `JWTAuthHandler` for the client to inject the auth header for you. I'm afraid that part has to be done by manually setting an auth header on requests. This is normally done in a way like this (using Vertx's WebClient):

```java
WebClient
      .create(vertx, ...) // set params so that this client can reach your API
      .post("/pets/pet123")
      .putHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token)
      // now make the actual request and use the results
```

How you get your hands on an auth token, depends. In your case, for the tests, your probably best bet is to use a mock auth service (instead of a real Keycloak). You need to configure your server to use the mock auth instead of real Keycloak for tests only (using configs) and for the client side, in your tests just get the token from it.

This mock auth service is an example of what would work: https://github.com/TNG/keycloak-mock